# How to only play sound when user submit data using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

The Code below displays users info and then play a sound when message is submitted and everything is working fine.

Now I have task of adding a typing notification event to the message form input as per  code below

```
onKeyDown={(event) => this.onKeyPressed(event)}
```

Hence the form input becomes

```
<input type="text" onKeyDown={(event) => this.onKeyPressed(event)} placeholder="Message" value={this.state.message} onChange={ev => this.setState({message: ev.target.value})}/>
```

Here is the typing notification function that I called

```
onKeyPressed(event) {

this.setState({typing:'someone is typing'});

}
```

**Here is my issue after adding typing notification:**

If user types for the first time and submit. it play sound and then display users info correctly. but as user
continues to types on the form input, the sound keeps playing continuously without stop. it seems the `onKeyPressed(event)` function is
causing application setState to re-render which causes the sound to continue to play without further form submission.

**What I want:**
Please how I prevent typing notification from playing sound as user types so that sound can only be played only if user
clicks on submit button

**here is the overall code**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";


class Sound extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
message: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {


 this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this);
this.onKeyPressed = this.onKeyPressed.bind(this);
  }



onKeyPressed(event) {

this.setState({typing:'someone is typing'});

}




 sendMessage = (message_text) => {

 alert(message_text);

 this.setState({

      data: [
        { id: "1", name: "user 1", message: "Hello from User1"},
        { id: "2", name: "user 2" , message: "Hello from User2"},
        { id: "3", name: "user 3", message: "Hello from User3"}
      ]
    });
        }


  render() {

    return (

          <div>
(---{this.state.typing}--)

                                 <input type="text" onKeyDown={(event) => this.onKeyPressed(event)} placeholder="Message" value={this.state.message} onChange={ev => this.setState({message: ev.target.value})}/>
                                <br/>
                                <span onClick={ () => this.sendMessage(this.state.message)}>Submit</span>

{this.state.data.map((message, i) => {


  if (message.message) {
if (message.message !=='') {
(new Audio('http://localhost/sound1.mp3')).play();
}

          return (
            <div key={i}>
       <div>   
 {message.name}: {message.message}
            </div>
              </div>
          )


  } else {

//(new Audio('http://localhost/sound2.mp3')).play();

  }
        })}



          </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend checking out the [lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) in react, and use the [componentDidUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) function:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // If we have new data (Thus a new message), play a sound:
  if (this.props.data.length > prevProps.props.data.length) {
    (new Audio('http://localhost/sound2.mp3')).play();
  }
}
```

Avoid playing sounds/etc in your render method. As you've noticed, any change to state or props will cause a rerender, and cause your component to continue to play sounds. Even worse, you have it in your map, so every new message, it will play a sound for EVERY message. On the 10th message, it will play the audio 10 times simultaneously.

Comment: I now understand the logic. Thanks